# Reduce Y axis labels on Dimple.js line chart

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I cannot reduce the number of Y axis labels on dimple.js line chart. I've tried to follow this solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305230/how-do-you-reduce-the-number-of-y-axis-ticks-in-dimple-js) but have no luck. Here is my sample code:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#ChartContainer", "100%", "100%");
var data = [{"Value(%):" 0.025, "Cost:" 95000},{"Value(%):" 0.26, "Cost:" 96000}, {"Value(%):" 0.027, "Cost:" 97000} ... etc etc. ( over 2000 pairs .. ) ];                               
 var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
 var x = chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Cost");
 var y = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Value(%)");
 y.addOrderRule("Cost");                                   
 var s = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line); 
 chart.addLogAxis("y", "Value(%)");                 
 chart.draw();
```

The chart draws ok, however, the Y axis labels make a complete mess. Here is what I got:
[image]

Can anyone point me what I've missing, sounds like something very basics, but spent good couple of hours to figure out, and no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any one, any help ???

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. The soluton is as described on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305230/how-do-you-reduce-the-number-of-y-axis-ticks-in-dimple-js) example, the only thing I was missing, is when to call that function, I was calling it AFTER the chart is drawn, but have to call it BEFORE chart draw function. Works as a charm.